# How to compare two power law distributions?

Tags: categorical-data, goodness-of-fit, genetics, bioinformatics, power-law

Disclaimer: I am a biologist, so please don't hesitate to correct me if I am making unwise assumptions.

I am looking at the distribution of a unique 6mer in a series of 2100mer (I have 415 independent 2100mer). More precisely, I am looking into how many times that 6mer is present in each 2100mer. As I deal with DNA sequence (A, T, G or C), each 6mer is expected to be found in random DNA every 4096 bp or 0.51 times in each 2100mer.
Clearly a non-normal distribution (qqplot).

Thus, I believe I am looking at a power law distribution or what should be a power law.

Now, I want to compare that observed distribution to a simulated one and see if they are the same.

Here are the raw counts:

```
RawObserved = c(87, 112, 111, 60, 20, 18, 7)  
RawExpected = c(44.6, 28.7, 19.0, 7.7, 2.0, 1.5, 0.5)
```

Here is my data rendered as proportion:

```
NormObserved = c(0.21, 0.27, 0.27, 0.14, 0.05, 0.04, 0.02) 
NormExpected = c(0.11, 0.07, 0.05, 0.02, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00)
```

I clearly cannot use a t-test but I was surprised to see that a chi-square test returned a non-significant result. To me those distributions look very different, qualitatively and I would like to statistically test that.

I hope my explanation is sufficient and makes sense.
Thanks!

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a biologist, so please don't hesitate to correct me if I use the wrong terminology or have a stupid question. **Questions**: (**1**) It is not clear to me what you are counting. Each array has length 7. What is this? (**2**) You have a 2100mer and are looking at a 6mer. Both lengths are divisible by 3 and so I am wondering if these 2100mer is "aligned" (i.e., "in frame") so that the first 3 base pairs correspond to the first amino acid, the next 3 to the second, etc.? (**3**) If not starting in-frame, then the answer will depend on the actual sequence of the 6mer, right?

Comment: @ Cardinal: Thanks for the opportunity for clarifying (1) In my observed set (i.e. the DNA sequence with my target 6 mer) I find up to 7 times the 6 mer. (2) No they are not aligned. (3) the frame is not relevant to my problem. Basically I expect to find each 6 mer in about every other sequence by chance, and finding 2, 3, or more times the 6 mer in the 2100mer sequence will be very rare.

Comment: From you data, it appears that it is more common for the 6mer to occur two or three times than only once. Also, if the alignment really isn't relevant, then how are instances counted? For example, let's say that I find a match at the 537th location. Do I skip forward six locations before searching again or only one? In the latter case the actual bases of the 6mer are important and will affect any analysis. For example, ATATAT will have a different probability distribution than AGCTCA, for example.

Comment: I don't understand why you're looking at a power law distribution. Seems to me a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) would be more appropriate here.  

Though I'm not sure I completely understand your data: You say you find up to 7 times the 6mer. I would expect the vector of counts to have length 8, but your RawObserved vector of counts has length 7. Were there no zero counts? Or are zero counts undetectable for some reason?

Comment: Even after adjusting for the problematically low expectations for some counts, a chi-squared test applied to the 'RawObserved' vs 'RawExpected' table will determine an *extremely* significant difference.  How, then, did you obtain a "non-significant result"?  There's something else wrong, too: the sums of raw and expected values should be the same.